# Short and concise, or real world example (for a question on Stack Exchange)

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I'm coming from [meta stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220113/should-big-edits-be-approved), Details are not important. I edited an answer there to *reduce complexity* by getting rid of the real-world example (essentially code bloat). So, would it really be beneficial for a reader to have a real world example (maybe get a firm grasp on what the OP wants to achieve), or would it make it harder to read/skim to have the question longer?

Do readers prefer short, concise questions, or long elaborative questions with a real example? (Keep in mind that the short question had *all information necessary* to figure out and solve the problem, the only difference is that a real example might be easier to get your head around)

Comment: If your question is "do people read stuff on the internet" then the answer is, sadly, no, mostly they don't. Unless they've gone out of their way to find it (like researching a particular topic and landing on a relevant article about it). But in general, regular reading, no. The more words you write the less of them that'll get read. http://uxmyths.com/post/647473628/myth-people-read-on-the-web

Comment: Thank you, @Jon That was what I expected.

Comment: OTOH, I've seen plenty of questions which elicit a comment response asking for more details of their problem, such as a screen capture or sketch.

Comment: @Erics Yes, but from my observations that's rarer. (tho still common)

Comment: If you're asking for a general UX response, and not one specific to SE ... it depends on the audience and response desired.

Comment: Also: http://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/

Comment: @Erics Yeah, the internet is a wide place.

Comment: Comment in general (not specific to the meta issue mentioned) When the question is about code, you need to consider that for most programmers it is far easier to spot the problem in a piece of code than in a description. So when the question is about code, I'd say an example can be instrumental in getting people to actually try and solve your problem/answer your question. Dependent upon the type of problem a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) __is__ essential to answering and many on SO will actually ask/demand it before even attempting to answer.

Comment: @Marjan That's one type of question. The other (this specific one) is about fundamentals which is like "I did text-align and it didn't work". It's a problem on _fundamentals_, not as much on long-codeblock-y-u-no-work questions. So, yes. It depends.

Comment: Meta? Ok, whatever.